# Polygon does not show fill color

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

In my map I have points that I can drag around the map to change the locations of polygon points. When a marker is moved I get the polygon I am editing from a class that keeps track of all my map elements, remove it from the map and plot a new polygon with the updated locations.

The problem I am having is when I move a point on one side of the polygon to the other, the fill color goes away until I move 2 of the other points.

Example

[image]

Result

[image]

Is this something that I am doing wrong or is this a bug in the API?

here is some of my code in the `onMarkerDragEnd`

```
String[] ary = marker.getSnippet().split("\\?");
        MapElement elem = mapElements.get(Long.parseLong(ary[0]));
        ArrayList<LatLng> polyPoints = elem.getLocationArray();
        polyPoints.set(Integer.parseInt(ary[1]), marker.getPosition());

    Polygon old = elem.getPolygon();
    Polygon p = map.addPolygon(new PolygonOptions().fillColor(0x500011FF).strokeColor(0x50444444)
        .strokeWidth(4).addAll(polyPoints));

    elem.setPolygon(p);

    old.remove();
```

basically the marker snippet holds the position of the point in the location array and then I get that position from the array and update it with the new position of the marker

Comment: I really don't like all the snippet parsing. You may want to use Marker.setData and Marker.getData from [Android Maps Extensions](http://code.google.com/p/android-maps-extensions/).

Comment: The same problem happens with complex but closed shapes without holes - as if intersection check have some rounding error or drop some points at certain zoom level. Play Services Lib 4.0.30 (889083-30)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61527262/google-maps-user-editable-polygon-with-fixed-number-of-points-in-android/61596226#61596226 please see my question

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using google-play-services v4, because ["Polygon vertices may now be ordered in clockwise or counterclockwise order."](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/releases#february_2013) (fixed in v5).

Update google-play-services in Android SDK Manager and import lib project again. Also you should have Google Play Services APK on your device in version 3.0.25 or above.

Comment: I am 99.9% sure this is not the issue because I did not start this project until that option was available. I plot polygons on the map also by pressing on the map and adding the new point to the `PolygonOptions` on each click then remove the old polygon and create a new one to show.

Comment: @tyczj You can add 0.01% there if you just look into Manifest of google-play-services_lib you are using and application details of Google Play Services on your device. "I did not start this project until that option was available." What option?

Comment: Yes I have version `3.0.27` on my device and I have the latest `google play services` loaded up. What I meant by "I did not start this project until that option was available." was the option to plot polygons in clockwise or counterclockwise order